# How to insert a buffer in a ostream with c++

Tags: c++

What i'm trying to do is to insert into a stream ( std::ostream ) a buffer .

this buffer is an attribute of my class "AcquiSample"

I made this example very simple for you to understand my problem.

here the definition of the class :

```
class AcquiSample
{
  public:
    IQSample * buffer;
}
```

here's the definition of the struct IQSample :

```
struct IQSample {
 struct {
    short val;
 }I;
struct {
    short val;
 }Q;
}
```

what I want to do is put this buffer with the known size into a stream like that:

```
std::ostream stream;
AcquiSample obj;
stream << obj.buffer->I.val << obj.buffer->I.val;
```

I think it's not working because it's not copying the data but the pointer adress, what i want is to put the entire buffer into this stream because i'm sending this stream on another computer.

If anyone know how to do this i'd be very thankful.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but I can see that obj.buffer is uninitialized in your example.

Comment: yeah let's suppose it is filled with data and i want to put those data into my stream

Comment: stream << obj.buffer->I.val << obj.buffer->Q.val; ?

Comment: yes , this line is to put the data into my stream but it's not working

Comment: You need to overload the `<<` insertion operator for your class and take the buffer contents

Comment: "let's suppose it is filled with data" - its a pointer. it *better* be filled with an valid *address*. How about throwing up a simple `int main()` example using your structure and a `ostringstream` as the target that exhibits something concrete rather than "its not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to achieve this is to overload the insertion operator:

```
struct IQSample {
 struct {
    short val;
 }I;
struct {
    short val;
 }Q;
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, IQSample iqs )
{
    return os << iqs.I.val << ' ' << iqs.Q.val; // Don't forget to put white spaces between the numbers!
}

std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& os, IQSample& iqs )
{
    return is >> iqs.I.val >> iqs.Q.val;
}
```

And now

```
std::ostream stream; // some stream bound to a streambuf who transfers over network
AcquiSample obj;
stream << *obj.buffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AcquiSample & sample)
{
    //Deserialize your object here, or create methods in AcquiSample for serialization and deserialization.
    os << sample.buffer->I.val;
    os << sample.buffer->Q.val;
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ostream stream; // Don't forget to initialize the stream.
    AcquiSample obj; // Don't forget to set buffer to something!
    stream << obj;
}
```